# Aptana File Diff?

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin, diff, aptana

Does Aptana have a file diff tool? Given it's a fairly standard dev requirement, I'm surprised there isn't one embedded in the IDE already. Does anyone have a good solution to this?

I haven't had much experience with eclipse but seeing that Aptana is built as an Eclipse plugin, would other Eclipse plugins be compatible?

Thanks!

--- **Answer:** (because it won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours) ---

Annnnnnnnd wouldn't you know it, after months of ruing the lack of file diff every time the need has arisen, I've just found the functionality within Aptana.

- Select 2 files in the various file lists within Aptana via CTRL+left click (i.e. the Project Explorer or Navigator panes)
- right click on the highlighted file you want to appear on the left of the diff screen and chose the 'Compare With' -> 'Each Other' option.

I just updated Aptana to the newest release today so I'm not sure if it's a new addition but I'd be willing to bet that it's been there for a long time and I am just a nonce.

Ta for clicking on my question anyway. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aptana does have file diff. It is under *Compare With* item when you right click a file in your project. Select two files and use *Compare With > Each Other* to see the diff between two local files. You can also compare your files with remote sources if you use synchronization or source control.

Comment: Thanks junjanes, I was just updating my question as you answered me here because I just found it myself! The functionality has been sitting under my nose for all this time! Cheers for dropping by to help me out though.

Hopefully this gets shown on Google because I couldn't find an answer to this every time I've searched for 'aptana file diff'.

Comment: Note that you need to be in the *Project Explorer* tab to get the option in the context menu, and not in the *App Explorer*

Comment: If you can't find Project Explorer like I couldn't: go to Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone ran to the same situation as mine.
I can't seem to compare a file from the Local Filesystem folder and the project folder.

What I did is select both files under the Filesystem folder.