# Aptana Studio 3 local/remote file compare

Tags: file, compare, aptana

I've been sampling Aptana to see if I prefer it over Dreamweaver, and I definitely want to use it going forward, but it's lacking one important feature I need - a simple way to compare a local vs. remote file before uploading.

I found some info in this thread, but it doesn't fully address my question:
[Aptana File Diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742486/aptana-file-diff)

The thread above mentions it's possible to compare local/remote if you synchronize, but if I right-click a file in Project View and select Synchronize, the ensuing menu doesn't seem to be doing anything. Or it might be trying to synchronize the whole site. But it's not clear to me how the sync is supposed to work. I don't want to risk unintentionally overlaying files in the remote environment.

If anyone could shed some light on this, please feel free!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to synchronize files over FTP with Eclipse RSE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947444/how-to-synchronize-files-over-ftp-with-eclipse-rse)